# Possible to set custom ringtones for Nexus 5 contact groups?

Tags: ringtone, nexus-5, contact-groups

I recently acquired my Nexus 5. While I'm absolutely in love with the device, I haven't been able to find a way to set a custom ringtone for specific contact groups.

Answer (score 0):

As a Nexus 5 owner I was not able to do without a specialized 3rd party app (I used Group Ringtone:
http://www.appbrain.com/app/group-ringtones/com.appventive.groupring). This feature seems to be missing in Android.

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading a app from the play store like ringtone maker, it worked for me.

Comment: Were you able to assign a ringtone to a contact *group* like the OP requests?